# Why does the printing stop with no errors?

Tags: java, while-loop

I try to print the result of boolean insert(K) in a for loop but after the first insertion the printing stops, that indicates the second insertion is not fully successful.

and inside method insert(K), the method "retrieves(K)" is called, to check if K has been already inserted.

```
    for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(m.insert(i +1, 22));
        System.out.println("dd");
        System.out.println(m.retrieve(i+1).first + ",,,"+m.retrieve(i+1).second);
        System.out.println(i + " insertion done");
        System.out.println("---------");
    }
```

and the result is

```
-------------------
true
dd
true,,,22
100 insertion done
---------
true
dd
```

After removing the "retrieves(K)" call in the insert() method, the print runs just fine, so i am assuming there is an issues with the method "retrieves(K)", and since there is no error + cpu usage is higher, it might be an infinite loop, the problem is, i don't see it.

here is the method "retrieves(K)"

```
    public Pair<Boolean, T> retrieve(K k) {

    Pair<Boolean, T> ff = new Pair<Boolean, T>(false, null);
    BSTMapNode<K, T> p = root;
    if(root==null) {
        return new Pair<Boolean,T>(false,null);
    }
    else
    while (p != null) {
        if (k.compareTo(p.key) == 0) {
            ff.first=true;
            ff.second=p.data;
            return new Pair<Boolean,T>(true,p.data);
        } else if (k.compareTo(p.key) < 0) {
            p = p.left;
        } else
            p = p.right;
    }
    return new Pair<Boolean,T>(false,null);
}
```

EDIT: added insert method

```
public boolean insert(K k, T e) {
    BSTMapNode<K, T> p = current;
    BSTMapNode<K, T> q = current;
    // ISSUE HERE
    if (retrieve(k).first == true) {
        current = q;
        return false;
        //
    }
    BSTMapNode<K, T> tmp = new BSTMapNode<K, T>(k, e);
    if (root == null) {
        root = current = tmp;
        return true;
    } else {
        if (k.compareTo(current.key) < 0)
            current.left = p;
        else
            current.right = p;
        current = p;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I can't spot an error in the retrieve() method. Please add the insert() method to your question, I think the problem must be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `insert()` method. When it is called for the second time, `root` is non-null, so execution gets into the else branch. There, it sets `current.left = p` with `current == p`, so `p` is now its own `p.left`. When the `retrieve()` method arrives at that node, it sets `p = p.left` which changes nothing, causing the infinite loop.

Your approach using a `current` node does not work. In `insert()`, you have to search the insertion position of the new node from the root every time, similar to what you do in `retrieve()`. Just keep going down until you reach a leaf. Then insert the new node there.

The code could look like this:

```
public boolean insert (K key, T value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new BSTMapNode<>(key, value);
        return true;
    } else {
        BSTMapNode<K, T> p = root;
        while (true) {
            if (key.compareTo(p.key) == 0) {
                return false; // Already in BST
            } else if (key.compareTo(p.key) < 0) {
                if (p.left == null) {
                    p.left = new BSTMapNode<>(key, value);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    p = p.left;
                }
            } else {    
                // Analogous for right sub-tree
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that i did not actually use the tmp variable, which was it should have been current.left=tmp instead of current.left=p, oh well ! i still used your code and it works great aswell, thank you..